# Filling up multiple translations

Tags: php, laravel, translation, laravel-blade

So i use this package [laravel-tranlatable](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable) , using his method of filling multiple translations, but i cant make it work , here is his guide for filling up multiple translation ..

```
$data = [
    'code' => 'gr',
    'en'  => ['name' => 'Greece'],
    'fr'  => ['name' => 'Grèce'],
  ];

  $greece = Country::create($data);

  echo $greece->translate('fr')->name; // Grèce
```

And here is what i do ,

**Controller**

```
$model = new Model([
            'el'=>[
                'name' => $request->input('el.name'),
                'description' => $request->input('el.description')
            ],
            'en'=>[
                'name' => $request->input('en.name'),
                'description' => $request->input('en.description')
            ],
        ]);

if($service->save()

     return redirect()->route('blabla.edit',compact('model'));
 }
```

**Blade**

```
{{ Form::text('en[name]', old('en[name]'),['class'=>'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::textarea('en[description]', old('en[description]'),['class'=>'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::text('el[name]',old('el[name]'),['class'=>'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::textarea('el[description]', old('el[description]'),['class'=>'form-control']) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$data = [
            'code' => request('code'),

```
        'tr'  => ['name' => $request->get('name')['tr']],
        'en'  => ['name' => $request->get('name')['en']],

    ];

    Country::create($data);
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation and/or context for this code?